# How can I resize an Image from remote URL before saving it

Tags: c#, image, resolution

This is my code to save images. The code works fine and i have no issues with it.

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();      

string strRealname = Path.GetFileName(ImageUrl);
string exts = Path.GetExtension(ImageUrl);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(ImageUrl, Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + id + exts);
```

I want to be able to save the image according to my SET dimensions. For example: an image I download is 600x300. I want to keep the original dimensions(2:1) and save it as 400x200. How can I do this?

**EDIT:** Maybe i Should have stressed this point. I dont want to save the orginal image from the URl. Some of the images would be more than 1000px in width or height. I want to downscale this before saving. this will be done for 1000's of Images and I dont want my server to run out of of disk space.

Comment: pick any duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=resize+image+c%23

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize an Image C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932546/resizeing-image, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137979/image-resizing-using-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748270/resizing-image-in-c-sharp, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613117/resizing-an-image-in-cm-c-sharp, do just as well

Comment: I hope you don't mean resize before downloading.. no can do for that.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this, but the simplest may be to use GDI+ and the [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics.aspx) class.

Instead of downloading a file, download a stream and create a Bitmap object from that using [`Bitmap.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536294.aspx).

Then create a new Bitmap with the dimensions you want and use [`Graphics.FromImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx) to create a Graphics object that will draw to that image.

Finally use the [`Graphics.DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yws82c40.aspx) to draw the downloaded image to the new one. Pass in the dimensions of the resized image to the method and you will get a Bitmap object containing the resized image that is ready to be written to disk.

NOTE: I am unable to setup a complete example at the moment, but this should be enough for you to sort it out.